# How to bind a key to a specific agenda command/list in org mode

Tags: org-mode, keymap

I've added a custom key for the org agenda to show all unscheduled TODO items following Sacha Chua:

```
(defun sacha/org-agenda-skip-scheduled ()
  (org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'scheduled 'deadline 'regexp "\n]+>"))

(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
   '(("u" "Unscheduled tasks" alltodo ""
      ((org-agenda-skip-function 'sacha/org-agenda-skip-scheduled)
       (org-agenda-overriding-header "Unscheduled TODO entries: ")))))
```

I can bring up this list with `C-c a u`, but I'd rather just bind it to a single key. Currently I have the simple:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") 'org-todo-list)
```

but I would like this to use the above custom command. I've had a dig through the manual but I can't see how to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping a call to `org-agenda` into a custom command and binding that to a key:

```el
(defun org-agenda-show-unscheduled (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (org-agenda arg "u"))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f8>") 'org-agenda-show-unscheduled)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't like creating an explicit function so I rolled my map within a lambda:

```el
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<f8>") '(lambda (&optional arg) (interactive "P")(org-agenda arg "u")))
```